# Remote access to smartphone from PC by knowing IP and MAC

Tags: ip, android, remote-access, mac-address, smartphone

I'm wondering if it's possible to transfer files from my smartphone (Android 9) to my PC (Ubuntu or Windows) without installing any app on the smartphone and without touching it. I'd like to perform these operations by using only the PC.

I know the public IP of my router, the private IP and the MAC address of my smartphone.

Comment: You say you know the public IP of your router, so I guess you want to transfer the files from outside your home network overthrew internet? Then you will probably need a third party app at least on your PC, otherwise it will be a very insecure connection. If you only want to transfer the files via LAN, then you can get away with making a folder/partition on your PC and opening it over LAN for other devices to access it, e.g. via SMB or WebDAV. If you tell me which your goal is I can most likely write an answer with more suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you want there is only one possible way that matches your requirements partially: **Use ADB over IP**.

Without an app on Android side ADB is the only way for file transfer over Wifi without touching the device. However the device has to be prepared once and and some actions have to be performed after every reboot:

#### Enable ADB (once)

On the device you need to enable the **Developer Options** menu (usually tapping ~5 times the build number in the Settings phone info). Then in the Developer Options you have to enable Android Debug Bridge.

On your PC you need at least the minimal ADB installation and base don your device the matching USB drivers for your device (Windows only).

Connect your phone via USB to the PC and check if `adb shell` open up a shell from the device

#### Enable ADB over IP (after every reboot)

For accessing ADB over IP (sometimes also called "adb Wifi" or "Wireless ADB") you have to enable ADB IP mode on the device. This can only be done using an USB connection. Once you have enabled ADB over IP it will stay until you reboot the device.

The details how to enable adb ip are already presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42364486/150978).

#### Accessing the files

If adb over IP has been enabled you can execute `adb connect <ip_address>:5555` and then upload/download files using `adb push`/`adb pull`.

For transferring more files you can use [adb sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync)`.

Note that ADB is a plaintext protocol. Therefore all files are transmitted without encryption or other protection. Only use adb over IP in a network that you trust (usually only a (Wifi) network you own.

And over adb you can even remote "control" (see screen and send touch and keyboard events) your phone using open source software [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy).

Comment: Nice answer sir. (+1)  I was ready to post the same one (only lower quality). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Likely not.  In order for your cellphone to communicate with other devices across WIFI it needs some kind of server on it - I do not believe that this is typically installed.

You might get slightly more traction by plugging the phone in to the PC using a data cable.   If you have done this before you might be lucky and be able to automatically have the PC find the Android data as a filesystem, but this is far from guaranteed and depends on how Android is configured among other things.